# Kafka partiton performance issue

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have 6 partitions for some topic and created a consumer group with 6 consumers. So, Here each consumer reading data from 1 partition. Here the problem is one partition having more data and other partitions having minimal data, due to data skew in one partition one consumer performing slow. How to handle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know which keys you are sending into the topic. If the keys are null, then this shouldn't be possible.

If there is a distribution of non-null keys that is skewed towards a few values, then those partitions will be greater.

You are welcome to write your own [`Partitioner`](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Partitioner.html) interface, otherwise.